# Storing the results of a SQLAlchemy query in an array

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, model

I am trying to store the result of SQLAlchemy statement in an array. But it is giving me Attribute error. Please help.

```
qry = (db.session.query(Customer))    
print(qry)

results = [
    {
        
        "customerID": getModelField(row.Customer, "id"),
        "network": getModelField(row.Customer, "network_num"),
        "customer": getModelField(row.Customer,"customer_name"),
        "email": getModelField(row.Customer, "customer_email"),
             
    }
    for row in qry.all()
]

out = {"results": results, "total": len(results)}
```

In the console, I am getting - AttributeError: 'Customer' object has no attribute 'Customer'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every row of your query result is a `Customer` object. Try `row.id` for your ID and so on.